# How to build a nuxt3 project in ssr mode for deploying

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have made a website by nuxt3 and django rest framework.
The problem is that I cannot build the nuxt project (that is coded by nuxt3) in the ssr mode to put it in the online hosting service.
Which command do I need to execute and What do I have to do to build this nuxt project in the ssr mode?
Thanks.

Comment: You have to build the project first. Run `npm run build`  to build nuxt3 project

Comment: @nur_riyad when I execute this command nuxt will generate some files and folders in output/server and when I put them in the public_html directory of my hosting it does not wor. I will thank to tell me your idea to solve this please.

Comment: nuxt generated file are not for SSR. Nuxt generate will prefetch all data and prerender all pages. It mainly generates file for static type hosting. For ssr you have to use `npm run build`

Comment: @nur_riyad I understand what you mean but when I execute the command npm run build, nuxt put some files and folders (such as index.mjs and index.map.mjs and package.json and node_modules folder and chunks folder) in output/server directory of my project and when I put them in the public_html directory of my web hosting service it does not work and the pages of my website are not shown.

Comment: which hosting service you are using?

Comment: @nur_riyad I have set my nodejs setting in the hosting service and I have also created a nuxt application for my project in there but I don't know where to upload the built project that is in the directory of output/server/ of the project in my desktop?Do I have to upload it in public_html or in the created application?